# Solve the differential equation ${y}''- 2{y}'- 3y= e^{3x}\left ( x^{2}+ 1 \right )$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, constants

> Solve the differential equation
> $${y}''- 2{y}'- 3y= e^{3x}\left ( x^{2}+ 1 \right )$$

by *jp*.[Wolfram|Alpha](https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27-2y%27-3y%3De%5E%283x%29%28x%5E2%2B1%29) that is $y= c_{1}e^{-x}+ c_{2}e^{3x}+ \frac{1}{12}e^{3x}x^{3}- \frac{1}{16}e^{3x}x^{2}+ \frac{9}{32}e^{3x}x.$ Can you explain to me why ? I realise that the result can be *seperated* into 2 parts actually the 1st one $c_{1}e^{-x}+ c_{2}e^{3x}$ received by solving the polynomial $a^{2}- 2a- 3$, I need to the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as $$(e^{-3x} y''-3e^{-3x}y')+(e^{-3x}y'-3e^{-3x}y)=x^2+1$$  Now integrating $$ e^{-3x} y'+e^{-3x}y=\frac{x^3}{3}+x+C$$ $$\iff e^xy'+e^xy=e^{4x}(\frac{x^3}{3}+x+C)$$  Now again integrate both sides and use Integration by parts in RHS..

You may use the fact that $e^xy'+e^xy=(e^xy)'$